# Redirect after java applet is run?

Tags: java, redirect, applet-servlet

I have googled around but have not come to an answer. The only thing close to my goal was utilizing meta redirect after X seconds, like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=index2.html">
```

What I need is php or html code that detects if my java applet has been run on the page, and then redirects to another file address.

How might I go about this, can someone be so kind as to throw me an example code?
Very much appreciated, thank you kindly for your time.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to redirect from your applet then write the code below:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class AppletExample extends Applet
{

public void init() {

try {
getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("http://www.google.com"), "_blank");//This is new tab/
getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("http://www.google.com"), "_parent");//This is in the parent tab/
}
catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
}

public void paint( Graphics g ) {

g.drawString("Go Google", 0,100);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the redirect triggered from within the applet I would try with the [showDocument()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29). It can be used like this:

```
this.getAppletContext().showDocument(URL, "_parent");
```